# Sieve of Eratosthenes in Scheme (R7RS)

Tags: performance, memory-management, scheme, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I've seen many implementations of Sieve of Eratosthenes in Scheme, but I thought I'd try to write one that is both space- and time-efficient:

- Space-efficient: I use R7RS bytevectors as a bitset, which encodes odd numbers starting with 3 (so bit 0 = 3, bit 1 = 5, bit 2 = 7, etc.).
- Time-efficient: Many implementations scan the table looking for the next viable prime. I instead use `first-set-bit` (analogous to `Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros` in Java) to avoid scanning each bit individually.

This code generates prime numbers up to at least n, and usually a handful more. It depends on [SRFI 60](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-60/srfi-60.html) for the bitwise operations.

```
(define (primes-up-to-about n)
  (define table
    (make-bytevector (+ (arithmetic-shift n -4) 1) 255))
  (define len (bytevector-length table))
  (define bitlen (arithmetic-shift len 3))

  (define (clear! i)
    (define q (arithmetic-shift i -3))
    (bytevector-u8-set! table q
                        (copy-bit (bitwise-and i 7) (bytevector-u8-ref table q) #f)))
  (define (next-marked-from i)
    (let loop ((q (arithmetic-shift i -3))
               (m (arithmetic-shift -1 (bitwise-and i 7))))
      (and (< q len)
           (let ((v (bitwise-and (bytevector-u8-ref table q) m)))
             (cond ((zero? v) (loop (+ q 1) -1))
                   (else (+ (arithmetic-shift q 3) (first-set-bit v))))))))
  (define (index->value i)
    (+ i i 3))

  (let loop ((rv '(2)) (i 0))
    (define next (next-marked-from i))
    (if (not next)
        (reverse rv)
        (let ((nextval (index->value next)))
          (do ((j next (+ j nextval)))
              ((>= j bitlen))
            (clear! j))
          (loop (cons nextval rv) next)))))
```

**I'm looking for ways to make the code more compact and/or elegant without sacrificing the space or time efficiency.**

In particular, if you can make a [SRFI 42](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-42/srfi-42.html) `:bitset` generator that actually does the equivalent of my `next-marked-from`, I can just turn the whole function into a `list-ec` comprehension. What's not to like? :-)

---

For people who want to test this program in Racket (since there aren't very many R7RS implementations currently around), add the following lines before the function definition:

```
(require srfi/60)
(define bytevector-length bytes-length)
(define bytevector-u8-ref bytes-ref)
(define bytevector-u8-set! bytes-set!)
(define make-bytevector make-bytes)
```

Comment: Hard coded numbers do not make the code easier to understand. Comments paying homage [or at least lip service] to *HtDP* might also make the code more accessible. Even a traditional Lisp style documentation string would help. There's a case to be made that both bullet points in the question should be an introduction in the source.

Comment: Most of the "hard coded numbers" (as used with `arithmetic-shift` and `bitwise-and`) are basically quicker ways to divide by 8 or 16 (and get the remainder). I could perhaps replace those with `truncate/` (or `quotient/remainder` in Racket). I didn't actually write the code for "ease of understanding" per se, though I suppose I should make a greater effort to do so. e.g., `m` (in `next-marked-from`) could have been named `mask`, since it masks out the bits we don't care about when calling `first-set-bit`.

Comment: In any case, I wanted to ensure that I have the best algorithm in place before I write docstrings or doc comments, since those would have to be rewritten if the algorithm substantially changes.

Comment: Head down in the maths and the language documentation, things seem obvious. When the code gets browsed by an idiot like me on Github, it's full of magic numbers - `divide-by-16` is a useful abstraction, particularly if the reason I'm looking at the code is because I am not up to speed on a bit-shifting sieve or the various related functions. For what it's worth, looking at the Racket code base, there appears to be a lot of code where comments were an unrealized afterthought.

Comment: Indeed, and I'm actually planning to split out the bitset into its own record type for better encapsulation and abstraction. Man, if this were Racket-specific, I'd just make a class and be done with it, but trying to be portable here. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, if it weren't for the hint in the first line (`define (primes-up-to-about n)`), I'd have no idea that this was an implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

The main problem, I think, is that names like `table`, `clear!`, and `next-marked-from` are all too low-level, not much better than the bytevector primitives, and devoid of contextual meaning.

To start, I think you should be able to rearrange the definitions.

```
  (define bytelen (+ (arithmetic-shift n -4) 1))
  (define primes-table (make-bytevector bytelen 255))
  (define bitlen (arithmetic-shift len 3))
```

Instead of `clear!`, try a more meaningful name like `mark-as-composite!`.

To complete the abstraction of the bytevector as a sieve, you would also need a helper function `(define (next-prime-above n) …)` that combines your `next-marked-from` and `index->value`.

`(reverse rv)` seems suspiciously expensive.  I think you should be able to build the list of primes in ascending order using smarter recursion.

Comment: Thanks for your review! 1. The original intent was to implement a bitset library, so the functions were named as bitset operations. I suppose it makes sense to use more domain-specific names. 2. I actually use the index from `next-marked-from` as the starting place for clearing the bitset flags. So with a `next-prime-above` refactor, I'd probably have to return two values, the index and the value. 3. `reverse` is a left-folding operation and is just as efficient as other left-folding operations like `for-each` and `sum`, and more efficient than right-folding operations like `map` and `filter`.

Comment: 3b. Accumulate-and-reverse is a pretty common idiom for simulating right-folding with a left-fold. The advantage of left-folding is that it's tail-recursive and thus doesn't eat up your call stack. I "could" make the function right-folding, which would eliminate the `reverse`, but it'd eat up a call frame for each prime number found, which could be problematic for huge numbers of primes.